# How can I find my followers?

Tags: fallout-4

The other day, while attempting to snipe an enemy, Dogmeat kept stepping in my way, so I told him to wait, out of the way. After all the action was over, I went and collected my loot, and went on my way. Without Dogmeat.

Fortunately, I remembered where he was, I managed to retrieve him. However, if this happened again, how can I locate Dogmeat, or any of my other followers, diligently waiting for my return?

Comment: Do you have the Vault-Tec Workshop DLC?

Comment: @TimmyJim no, vanilla only

Comment: Dang, you could have used [this terminal](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-4/How_to_Locate_Your_Companions).